# group duplicates ID, but show the rest of the information

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

master (major, SID, fee)

```
Biology, 13578, $500
Physics, 12460, $400
```

student (major, SID, fname, lname, startDate, lastDate)

```
Science, 73589, Steven, Archer, 2010-09-02, null
Biology, 13578, Stacy, Diaz, 2009-09-02, null
Sociology, 21749, Gavin, Wall, 2011-01-05, null
Physics, 12460, Pat, Dunn, 2012-09-02, null
```

I have to make a query where it shows the information of all master students grouped by their major and their fee.

I tried it this way:

```
select * from from master, student 
where master.SID=student.SID AND master.major=student.major 
group by student.SID;
```

But this will make SID and major info to show twice:

```
Biology, 13578, Stacy, Diaz, 2009-09-02, null, Biology, 13578
Physics, 12460, Pat, Dunn, 2012-09-02, null, Physics, 12460
```

so now I have this:

```
select distinct student.sid, student.eid, fname, lname, startDate, lastDate, fee
from from master, student 
where master.SID=student.SID AND master.major=student.major 
group by student.SID;
```

which will give:

```
Biology, 13578, Stacy, Diaz, 2009-09-02, null
Physics, 12460, Pat, Dunn, 2012-09-02, null
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to not specify which SID or major to select. I want it to select all but it deletes duplicates.

Sorry if this seems easy, I'm still a beginner in mysql

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help clarify what you're trying to do...

Comment: It's edited with results/sample data

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to `select *`, but have redundant columns removed.

This isn't possible, but you can take a shortcut by returning all the columns from `student`, and then add the additional column from `master`.

```
select s.*, m.fee
from
  master m
  join student s 
    on s.sid = m.sid
    and s.major = m.major
```

Notice that I made a few other changes to your query:

1. Replaced the implicit join (`student, master`) with an explicit join (`master join student`).
2. Removed the `group by` and `distinct`... I don't believe that they are necessary for what you're trying to do.
3. Added table aliases (`m` and `s`).

One final suggestion... it is widely considered bad practice to use `select *` for a variety of reasons... so even though there's a shortcut for what you're trying to do, [it would be best to list out all of your columns for other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to specify which table to pull from if there are duplicate column names, or you'll get an error. You can specify both, of course: SELECT master.SID, student.SID.